# flask run command on a flask app with flask-socketio extension

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

I have a very simple flask application that integrates flask-socketio, and I am trying to run my server using the `flask run` command on my terminal. I have read the documentation and this should do the job, however the output is the following, and I cannot reach my server on 127.0.0.1:5000

[image]

and here is my code:
[image]

I would really appreciate any help :)

Comment: Try `127.0.0.1:5000` instead of `127.0.0.1/5000`

Comment: sorry that was a writing typo, I do use 127.0.0.1:5000

Comment: If you do exactly what error msg "WebSocket transport not ..." states it will work.

Answer (score 0):

the problem mainly was because I was using the latest version of flask (flask 1.0) if i revert back to flask 0.12.2  running the server using flask run will work as expected.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the following code snippet to host your falsk app on localhost with port number as 5000 at the end of your code.

```
app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000)
```

I hope, it helps!